# how to declare and initialize ArrayList in C# of Visual Studio Professional Edition 2008

Tags: c#, arraylist

I am encountering challenges in declaring `ArrayList` in C# windows app. I'm using Visual Studio Professional Edition 2008.

I tried this code:

```
ArrayList myArray = new ArrayList();
```

But I got the exception:

> "The type or namespace name 'ArrayList' could not be found(are you
>   missing a using diective or an Assembly reference?)"

Pls Guys help me out.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `ArrayList` rather than https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely not importing it - `ArrayList` is part of the `System.Collections` namespace. Include the following line at the top of your code:

```
using System.Collections;
```

Source: [MSDN Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ben Kolya Mansley thanks for your quick intervention to my challenge!